# How do I change the IP address on Oracle 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ip-address

What steps do I need to take to change an IP address for Oracle 10g? I cannot connect to the database after going from a dhcp address to a static IP and a reboot.

Comment: I changed the tnsnames and listener IP addresses, but now I get an error related to the TNS not finding the sid requested.

Comment: Based on recent events, I'm thinking the issue is with the Listener not detecting the old instance on the new IP.

Answer (score 4):

If the server's IP address changed, these are the first things I would look at:

The TNSNAMES.ORA file on the client -- does it have the IP address hardcoded?  If so, change it.  Does it use the machine name?  If so, does the machine name resolve to the correct IP address on your client machine?

The LISTENER.ORA file on the server -- does it explicitly specify the old IP address as its listening address?

Answer (score 2):

More info please. Do you mean that you have changed the ip address of the host that the database is on and now you have to connect to it from a different macine, or are you having trouble starting the database after the ip change?

... and what error message do you receive?

Answer (score 2):

Most obvious files to check are:

$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora

Other than that we'd need more info...

- I presume you mean the Oracle 10g DB and not the Oracle 10g Application Server?
- Does the database start ok?
- Is there anything in the database alert log?
- Are the error(s) connecting from a client or the server?
- What error message(s) do you get?
- Can you ping the machine on it's new address (by both name + IP address)  From both client + server?
- Does a TNSPING work?
- Can you connect using SQL*Plus on the server?
- What other tool(s) have you tried connecting with?

**Update after comment**

Please can you post...

- Your old ip address (if you know it)
- Your new ip address
- Your FQDN (e.g. machine.domain.com)
- The output of "ipconfig/all" (or equivalent)
- Your listener.ora file
- The output of "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl start"
- The output of "$ORACLE_HOME/bin/lsnrctl status"

Comment: Yes, the database starts fine. The listener just does not recognize the new database.

Answer (score 1):

Check that LOCAL_LISTENER is not defined (or defined correctly) in the database - it may not be registering correctly because of an incorrect entry here. Also try 'ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER' to attempt to register with the listener (rather than waiting up to 3 minutes for an auto-register). Examine the listener.log to see the instance registered (service_update * ) and 'lsnrctl status' to see if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the hostname in DNS? Can you ping the hostname from another machine?